# Automated formula to proportional distributing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have the lowest point **C**.
And I got max point **D**.

How to automate formula to spread bank **B** between **A** users?

Growing proportional, where A, B, C and D can be edited and rebuild the list.

*Screenshot shows almost right result in SUM (3,87), it's created manually to show what I'm looking for.*

[image]

- Google Sheets sample:
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_VMyIrnPtj4KrIe2irCQGGXaTWKrL1oJrd-iFq_Evo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please provide the outcome you are trying to get?

Comment: The 1st place need to have D sum (1), the 12th place need to have C sum (0,05). But how to automatically, proportionally spread remaining bank B (3,87-1,05=2,82) between 2nd and 11th places in a growing rate?

Comment: Please check the update, I manually generated nearly result what I'm looking for in F,G.

Comment: I see you have changed the actual TITLE of your post.  It used to say linearly, and now it says "growing proportionally".  That distinction has an enormous impact on the question you were asking.  What you're asking for is a best fit exponential trendline given you know the "area under the curve".  My memory goes to "Laplace" from calculus in high school.  I will try to figure it out, but you should know you changed the question quite a bit.

Comment: Is your idea to have a constant growth rate? If that's the case, I think this is an overdetermined system of equations.

Comment: @MattKing yes, right now I realized the correct model to implement my objective. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @lamblichus yes, now task objective is totally correct.

Comment: @Iamblichus we got known min and max levels, quantity of users and amount of bank, that must be enough to generate a list? You mean Google Sheets don't have required instruments?

Comment: No, I mean that mathematically, not all conditions can be met. If you know the min, the max and the quantity of users, and you know that the growth rate should be constant, the distribution is already defined. The amount of bank condition cannot be met.

Comment: @Iamblichus you are totally right, rn I rebuild the formula and will try to just search growth coefficient from MIN without MAX parameter

Answer (score 1):

I think this formula should work.  I put it on your sample sheet under the text MK.Help.

It works by using the SEQUENCE() formula to create steps that are subtracted from the maximum amount.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(D2-SEQUENCE(A2;1;0)/((A2-1)/(D2-C2)))
```

Comment: It results a sum 24,38, but the bank is 3,87; 1st place got to win = 1, and 12st place have to win = 0,05.

Comment: Please check the update, I manually generated nearly result what I'm looking for in F,G.